# Flutter NetworkImage errors

Tags: flutter

Flutter looks promising, but now and then I am stuck. In this case the error states:

```
package:async/src/typed/stream.dart': error: line 56: class 'TypeSafeStream' overrides method 'firstWhere' of super class or interface 'Stream' with incompatible parameters
```

I am using the following code that should work:

```
new NetworkImage(googleSignIn.currentUser.photoUrl)
```

fluttor doctor outputs:

```
[✓] Flutter (on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E139j, locale nl-NL, channel dev)
    • Flutter version 0.1.2 at /Users/johngorter/Desktop/flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision 8a65872ef9 (6 days ago), 2018-02-13 23:32:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 05c5f817eb
    • Tools Dart version 2.0.0-dev.22.0
    • Engine Dart version 2.0.0-edge.3c4dccbd46f152be9e1b6ca95c57357e8e48057c

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/johngorter/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK at /Users/johngorter/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 26.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.2, Build version 9C40b
    ✗ libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller are not installed. To install, run:
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
    ✗ ios-deploy not installed. To install:
        brew install ios-deploy
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without resolving iOS dependencies with CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.io/platform-plugins
      To install:
        brew install cocoapods
        pod setup

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] VS Code (version 1.20.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Dart Code extension version 2.8.2

[✓] Connected devices
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I am not using IOS (for now) and I am using VSCode.. so the issues are not causing the errors...

Is it something I have done to cause this or is it a bug in the packages?

Comment: Either your Flutter version or packages you're using are not up-to-date. This  is a common error caused by the changes made for the transition to Dart 2.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `flutter doctor -v` and check if `flutter packages upgrade` helps. If `flutter packages upgrade` prints a list of dependencies then this list should contain information which of your dependencies are outdated. It doesn't always print this list, but I have no idea why or how to make it do so.

Comment: I added the flutter doctor output, I also tried a flutter packages upgrade, but with no result, I still see the same error message in the output..

Comment: That doesn't look like a recent version but I can't see the Flutter version number in the output. Can you please use the `-v` option and replace the content in your question with the new output?

Comment: Ok, your Flutter is the latest version. I just saw a similar issue in Gitter. There it was mentioned that switching to the `master` channel fixed it.

Comment: That actually did the trick, so the conclusion is that there is a bug in the dev branche of flutter at this moment?

Comment: There might just be some dependency that needs an update (perhaps the `http` package to be compatible with the most recent Flutter version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the `master` channel or

adding

```
dependency_overrides:
  async: ^2.0.4
```

to `pubspec.yaml` 
and run `flutter package upgrade should do as workaround until the problem is solved.